# mySQL reusing calculated value in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

```
SELECT 
  table1.a,
  table1.b, 
  (SELECT b 
  FROM table2 
  WHERE table2.b - table1.a < 10 
  LIMIT 0,1) as test
FROM table1 
WHERE table1.b < test;
```

I'm trying to use the result received in the SELECT "variable" **test** in the WHERE part of my query.

Any idea how to do that without having to redo the calculation or whatsoever in the WHERE again? That's how i managed to make it work so far.

Comment: Not possible, you can not use aliases in the WHERE clause. But just repeating the exact same calculation in the WHERE clause is usually not an issue, this gets optimized internally, so that the calculation happens only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use it in WHERE but you can use HAVING for it. There you have your result. But thats not very performant.

```
SELECT table1.a, table1.b,
  (select b FROM table2 WHERE table2.b-table1.a<10 LIMIT 0,1) as test 
FROM table1
HAVING table1.b<test
```

If you want to use WHERE, then you have to create your SUBSELECT at this position too

```
SELECT table1.a, table1.b,
  (select b FROM table2 WHERE table2.b-table1.a<10 LIMIT 0,1) as test 
FROM table1
WHERE table1.b < (select b FROM table2 WHERE table2.b-table1.a<10 LIMIT 0,1)
```

Comment: Can't I do something like this `SELECT table1.a, table1.b,
  @test:=(select b FROM table2 WHERE table2.b-table1.a<10 LIMIT 0,1) as test 
FROM table1
WHERE table1.b <@test`

Answer (score 0):

I think , this query will give the result as you want .

```
SELECT table1.a ,
 table1.b ,
 table2.b 
FROM table1 ,
 table2 
WHERE 
table1.b < table2.b AND
 (table2.b - table1.a) < 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `test` variabel is equal to `table2.b` that's value is less than `table1.a +10`. Thus it is possible to convert the query to

```
SELECT 
  table1.a,
  table1.b, 
  table2.b AS test
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 
ON (table2.b - table1.a < 10) AND (table1.b < table2.b)
GROUP BY table1.a, table1.b;
```

The `GROUP BY` clause is used here to prevent duplication of `table1.a`and 
 `table1.b` combinations and to get just first `table2.b` value for each `table1.a` and `table1.b` combination.